# How to find random numbers that can sum up to n?

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

I have a random integer $n$ and another integer called the summary. I want to know how many ways I can sum a subset of numbers from $1$ to $n$ to produce the value of summary.

For example, I have $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10$ and the summary is $18$.
The expect result is:

1. $10 + 8$
2. $6 + 4 + 8$
3. $1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 8$
4. ....

Is there any algorithm or formula for this problem?

Comment: Do you want to know the _number_ of different subsets of $\{1\ldots n\}$ that sum to $S$ (your summary), do you want to know how to _list_ all of them, or do you want to know how to _choose_ one of them at random?  Your question seems to ask all three simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of algorithms, one way you can approach it is by building up a table.

Let $P(S, n)$ be the number you are interested in, then $$P(s,n) = P(s-n, n-1) + P(s-n+1, n-2) + ... + P(s-2, 1)$$

Then go around building up a table and keeping in mind $P(0, n) = 1$ and $P(x, n) = 0$ when $x < 0$.  I haven't fully checked if this algorithm works so report back on your findings.

Remember to use [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) so that you don't have to repeatedly do massive recursive calls.